# Select table from database where value is X

Tags: mysql

So far I've found out that this gives me a list of all the tables which has the column name "store_id" - but I only want it to select the columns if "store_id" = 4, how could I do this?

Right now I use this to find the tables which has the "store_id" column.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('store_id')
AND TABLE_SCHEMA='db1';
```

Comment: use a stored procedure for this. First loop through all the tables which have columns with name `store_id`. then put a where condition in your select query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can it with dynamic SQL like this

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT 
         CONCAT('SELECT ''', TABLE_NAME, 
                ''' table_name FROM ', TABLE_NAME, 
                ' WHERE store_id = 4')
         SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL ')
  INTO @sql
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'store_id'
   AND TABLE_SCHEMA = SCHEMA();

SET @sql = CONCAT(@sql, ' ORDER BY table_name');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Sample output:

```
| TABLE_NAME |
-------------|
|     table1 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dad9b/8)** demo

---

Now you can simplify things on calling end by wrapping it up into a stored procedure

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE list_tables(IN _column_name VARCHAR(64), IN _column_value VARCHAR(256))
BEGIN
  SET @sql = NULL;

  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT 
           CONCAT('SELECT ''', TABLE_NAME, ''' table_name
                     FROM ', TABLE_NAME, 
                  ' WHERE ', _column_name,  ' = ''', _column_value, '''')
           SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL ')
    INTO @sql
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
   WHERE COLUMN_NAME = _column_name
     AND TABLE_SCHEMA = SCHEMA();

  SET @sql = CONCAT(@sql, ' ORDER BY table_name');

  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

And use it like this

```
CALL list_tables('store_id', '4');
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c7f50/2)** demo

Answer (score 0):

Use IF clause in `MySQL`.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
IF(store_id = 4)
    COLUMN_NAME = store_id
END IF;
```

**OR**

You can use `case` statement.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE CASE WHEN store_id = 4
           THEN COLUMN_NAME = store_id
```

Comment: `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` does not have a column named `store_id` so both queries will fail.